# MVC Flushing Earlier asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, stream, chunked

**What I want to do**  Create a fragment class which will call fragment service parallelly for each fragment. Fragment service will make a request to get content then write the response and flush streams to the browser.

I tried the code below but it did not work because fragment service can't reach the context properly.

**My question is** what is the best way to implement my goal in ASP.NET MVC 5

---

> Here is my view

```
<div>
    @Fragment.Render()
</div>
```

> Here is my Fragment Class

```
public static async Task<ActionResult> Render(string names){

    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    Task t1 = Task.Run(() => FragmentService.Get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corysimmons/colors.json/master/colors.json", context));
    Task t2 = Task.Run(() => FragmentService.Get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlohmann/json/develop/CMakeLists.txt", context));
    Task t3 = Task.Run(() => FragmentService.Get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlohmann/json/develop/meson.build", context));

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);

    return new JsonResult();
}
```

> Here is my Fragment Service

```
public Task Get(string url, HttpContext context){

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        using (var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    context.Response.Write(line);
                    context.Response.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run` for I/O work?

Comment: @KennethK. I want to start each call parallelly

Comment: When you say 'parallely' do you actually mean asynchronously? i.e. non-blocking? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: `Task.Run` is for CPU-bound work. Making web requests is I/O-bound work. Simply collect the resulting tasks of each `Get` call into a list or array, and then `await Task.WhenAll` the list or array.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane yes exactly asynchronously. My goal is, make requests without blocking each other, then, write their responses to the context.response and flushing each line of stream.

Comment: @KennethK. so you are saying that, I should get rid of Task.Run

Comment: Yes. The `Get` method is already async-ready. Just `await` the appropriate bits in that method. And don't use `.Result` in ASP.NET because it can result in a deadlock in certain situations.

Comment: How do you know when the task completes? response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync() Does not block so you need an indication when you get the entire stream.

Comment: @jdweng But `.Result` does block.

Comment: I removed all (.Results) and put await for all async operations, now everything is async but MVC closes httpcontext.response and I could not  flush my stream. I need to to keep alive TCP connection with the browser till my async operations done.

Comment: How does .Result know the end of a binary data?  It may work for a one line string and may not work for binary.

Comment: @jdweng yes, the problem is here, there must be some way to keep TCP connection alive till my async operations done. If I can find a way, I will be able to  create an event to end response after my async operations

Comment: Binding to a Networkstream may work.